# ReceiveAsync not receiving websocket messages in C#

Tags: c#, websocket

I want to receive message from `websocket` (broker's websocket to get live stock data) after I send some message to server. I created dummy websocket server in Nodejs by which I can receive message from server but when I try to use client's websocket, it is not working.

Please note : I am able to connect to client's websocket.

Below are methods which I have used to `connect`, `send` and `receive`

`Connect` method

```
public static async Task Connect(string uri)
{
    ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

    try
    {
        webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        webSocket.Options.SetRequestHeader("x-session-token", "efcb0a89db75d4faa147035461224182");
        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
      
        await Task.WhenAll(Send(webSocket), Receive(webSocket));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (webSocket != null)
            webSocket.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine();

        lock (consoleLock)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
}
```

For send, I want to send JSON data to server so that it will return me result accordingly. below is `Send` method

```
private static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
{
    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        

        Symbol[] sym =
        {                    
             new Symbol
             {
                 symbol = "1330_NSE"
             }
        };               

        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody()
        {
            request = new Request
            {
                streaming_type = "quote",

                data = new Data()
                {
                    symbols = sym
                },
                request_type = "subscribe",
                response_format = "json"
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

        var sendBuffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            
        await webSocket.SendAsync(sendBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

Below is `receive` method

```
private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to run it comes up to `websocket.ReceiveAsync` function and does nothing after it

```
var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

[image]

I think, it is not waiting to receive messages from server?

Also I want to know if there is any way by which I can confirm that message I send from `send` method get sent to server or not ?

Comment: Try using a proxy like Fiddler to see what messages are actually being sent.

Comment: @StephenCleary I can see headers in Fiddler but is there any way by which we can confirm what message we send to server?

Comment: I thought Fiddler would show you the websocket messages, too.